# How do I integrate GEVA into Clojure

Tags: java, interop, clojure

I am getting into Clojure and Grammatical Evolution at the same time and discovered [GEVA](http://ncra.ucd.ie/Site/GEVA.html), which is a GE tool written in Java.  I have no background in Java.  So I don't have to re-invent the wheel, how can I integrate GEVA into Clojure?

I can execute the default script from the CLI with:
    java -jar GEVA.jar -main_class Main.Run

The GEVA source directory has the following subdirectories with packages named after the directory:
Algorithm  com  Exceptions  FitnessEvaluation  Fractal  Individuals  Main  Mapper  Operator  Parameter  UI  Util

The Main subdirectory has the following files and tutorial subdir:
AbstractRun.java  Experiment.java  Run.java  State.java  Tutorials

The following classes are in the Run.java file:
    public class Run extends AbstractRun
        public Run()
        public void experiment(String[] args)
        public void setup(String[] args)
        private void setSeed()
        public static void main(String[] args)

From what I can tell, the static method 'main' in class Main.Run is what I want to execute.  However when I try to follow the Java interop instructions, I am getting errors.

```
clgeva.test=> (.Main.Run/main)
java.lang.Exception: No such namespace: .Main.Run (NO_SOURCE_FILE:5)
clgeva.test=> (.Main.Run/main "")
java.lang.Exception: No such namespace: .Main.Run (NO_SOURCE_FILE:6)
```

I'm obviously not importing the namespace correctly to run the main function.

```
user=> (import Main)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
user=> (import Main.Run)
Main.Run
user=> (main)
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: main in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:3)
user=> (.Main.Run/main)
java.lang.Exception: No such namespace: .Main.Run (NO_SOURCE_FILE:4)
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?  I am sure I'm just missing something obvious, but I've been banging my head on it for a little while and need some direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for calling a static method with no arguments (I'll use an example that everyone has access to) is:

```
=> (java.lang.System/currentTimeMillis)
1284574337322
```

The above form is preferred, but the following is also possible, and can be useful in macros:

```
=> (. java.lang.System currentTimeMillis)
1284574477369
```

In this case, "java.lang." may be omitted, but I'm including it to match your case more closely.

```
=> (System/currentTimeMillis)
1284574617771
```

Adding a dot to the first form will not work, whether with or without a space:

```
user=> (.System/currentTimeMillis) 
java.lang.Exception: No such namespace: .System (NO_SOURCE_FILE:44)
user=> (. System/currentTimeMillis)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed member expression, expecting (. target member ...) (NO_SOURCE_FILE:45)
```

Comment: This answer provided the closest hint to what I was doing wrong.  I was correctly setting the class with the following:

Comment: This answer provided the closest hint to what I was doing wrong.  I was correctly setting the class with the following from the lein repl when the jar was in the lib folder:
    (ns clgeva.test (:import Main.Run))

When I searched through the results of (ns-imports *ns*), I found 'Run Main.Run' which indicated that the class was imported as Run.

So when I ran (Run/main ""), I got a classCastException error which indicated that I was on the right path.  Fixing that with the following (Run/main (into-array [""])) got the code to execute as expected.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you are loading the GEVA lib correctly - see http://clojure.org/libs
I'm guessing, from the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error, that GEVA is not on your classpath.

Then you want to look at the Clojure documentation for Java interop: http://clojure.org/java_interop

Comment: I've tried loading the classpath a couple of ways.  The first way I ran was by copying the GEVA.jar file into the leiningen lib folder, then executing 'lein repl'.  The other way was to manually execute 'java -cp clojure.jar:clojure-contrib.jar:GEVA.jar -jar clojure.main'.

Comment: Actually...I'm not in front of my machine...I don't think I had that -jar in the manual execution of the previous comment.

Comment: For leiningen, you want to specify GEVA as a dependency in your DEFPROJECT form in project.clj (see http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/project.clj for an example).

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you do have some syntax errors.

```
clgeva.test=> (.Main.Run/main)
```

Should have a space between the dot operator and the Main.Run/main reference. As it is, it's trying to find something called ".Main.Run" which obviously doesn't exist. Do it like so:

```
clgeva.test=> (. Main.Run/main)
```

Assuming you have your classpath set up correctly, it should work.

Importing the class using `(import ...)` and calling `(main)` won't work because `main` is a static method.